# Which diagnostic tests are suitable for Measuring Total Factor Productivity (TFP)?

Tags: econometrics, production-function, productivity

I did the TFP estimation with Levinsohn Petrin (in R) but I have doubts about the diagnostic tests e.g. I know that the estimation of [autocorrelation in residuals](http://www.yorku.ca/andreyst/files/Stata-code_for_publication.do) has to be done (it would be very helpful if the library to be used can be stata or R) I also read if there are **constant returns to scale**.

Comment: "it would be very helpful if the library to be used can be stata or R." But the link you provide already gives you steps (and even just a a command how to perform it directly at the end) in stata

Comment: The codes on the website only worked 2 in my case so I thought maybe there would be other tests.